# How to implement addRegistry(Registry registry) method in apache camel 3.4.0?

Tags: java, apache-camel

We updated one of our projects from camel 2.25.2 to 3.4.0 recently.
There was a class called `CompositeRegistry`, but Camel documentation says it's deprecated or not available in new versions.

So we used `DefaultRegistry` class and it does not have `addRegistry` method.

Our old code used `CompositeRegistry` class and its methods. How can I solve this issue?

Old code:

```
private void registerSoapEndpoint() {
    
    SimpleRegistry simpleRegistry = new SimpleRegistry();
    CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = new SoapEndpoint().getCxfEndpoint();
  
    simpleRegistry.put("TrobuleTicketEndpoint", cxfEndpoint);
    CamelContext camelctx = getContext();

    CompositeRegistry compositeRegistryTest = new CompositeRegistry();

    compositeRegistryTest.addRegistry(camelctx.getRegistry());
    compositeRegistryTest.addRegistry(simpleRegistry);
    ((DefaultCamelContext) camelctx).setRegistry(compositeRegistryTest);
    
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading the migration guide(s), like [Apache Camel 2.x to 3.0 Migration Guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html), your specific problem is covered [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_generic_information)), and maybe also for intermediate 3.x versions as listed on [Apache Camel 3.x Upgrade Guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3x-upgrade-guide.html).

Answer (score 1):

The out of the box registry has a `bind` method so you can add to it - you no longer need to composite anymore.

Comment: @NK95 if this answered your question then please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick mark